# Anatomy of a production rule

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars

Production [is said to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_(computer_science)) of the form $u \to v$. I want to know if you distinguish $u$ from $v$ giving them some distinguishing names, like LHS/RHS or something alike.

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is more a request to use uniform terminology (good luck with that!).

Comment: @vonbrand The question is whether there are distinguishing names for the two sides of the rule. It seems quite clear to me -- perhaps you misread it?

Comment: $v$ can be said to be the production of the string $u$ by the rule at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$u$ can be called the 'head' (or left-hand side)

$v$ can be called the 'body' (or right-hand-side)

sources: [source-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar), [source-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols)

Comment: I've never seen the terms *head* or *body* for this, while *left hand side* and *right hand side* are common.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have found it in *Parsing techniques: A practical guide*

> For brevity we write ---> instead of “may be replaced by”; since
>   terminal and non-terminal symbols are now identified as technical
>   objects we shall write them in a typewriter-like typeface. The part
>   before the ---> is called the **left-hand side**, the part after it the
>   **right-hand side**.