# How do you call alternatives in the grammatical productions?

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars

I have encountered a question, which asks [what is a *syntactic form*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885679/definition-of-the-term-syntactic-form). This motivated me to ask myself, what is the [anatomy of the grammatic rule](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51107/anatomy-of-a-production-rule),

```
     S ::= A | B | C
```

Anatomy established that `S` is called *LHS* whereas `A | B | C is` called expectedly *RHS*. But, how do you call the individual alternatives within the RHS? Is it related to your syntactic forms?

Comment: Um... "alternatives"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > how do you call the individual alternatives within the RHS?

As @Rafael mentioned, they are called *alternatives*.

Parsing Techinques: A Practical Guide, 2nd ed. (2008) by D. Grune and  C.J.H. Jacobs, page 15:

> There is a more compact notation, in which several right-hand sides for one and the same left-hand side are grouped together and then separated by vertical bars, **|**. This bar belongs to the formalism, just as the arrow $\to$, and can be read “or else”. The right-hand sides separated by vertical bars are also called *alternatives*.

2. > Is it related to your syntactic forms?

From the same source (p. 13):

> Non-terminals [`S`, `A`, `B`, `C` in the example] are called (grammar) variables or *syntactic categories* in linguistic contexts.

It seems the terms *syntactic form* and *syntactic category* are used somewhat interchangeably.
So, if an alternative is a variable, then it represents a syntactic form, but if it has more complex structure (it can contain terminals, or several non-terminals), then we might say that from the point of view of the grammar's author the alternative does not represent a syntactic form. But someone else can always turn it into one by defining a new non-terminal with an appropriate RHS.

Since B.C. Pierce's syntactic forms include terminals (`true`, `false`, `0`), I agree with the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26892992/2747511) that the term *syntactic form* is used somewhat informally and is not defined precisely.

Comment: Should they have different syntactic forms?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question (especially the meaning of the word "have" here). I'd say the alternatives *define* (normally different) syntactic forms. Does it make anything clearer?

Comment: If we turn to the TAPL example from the [first link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885679/definition-of-the-term-syntactic-form), then it says, that a *term* (`t`) is either `true` (syntactic category consisting of only 1 element), or `false`, or an`if`-expression (syntactic category of infinite number of elements), etc.

Comment: Does it mean that syntactic forms and alternatives are the same things, syntactic form is what the alternative defines?

Comment: I've updated the answer, trying to clarify that part.

Comment: One parser author once told me that different syntactic forms allow to differentiate between alternatives so that I started to believe that syntactic form is the grammar/syntax of the syntactic category (non-terminal that we can meet in the alternative).